# Update JIRA custom fields from Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jira, devops, jenkins-groovy, jira-plugin

I need to update JIRA custom fields(fix branch and fix versions) with JIRA ID (COPR-50320) from Jenkins pipeline.
Actually, I new to Jenkins. But I have done successful integration of JIRA to JENKINS.
So, I am not clear how to get JIRA issue based on id (I get this id from SVN) and update fields using this id.

[image]

Comment: Hi ,Are you using what kind of interface to access the JIRA fields ,is it through REST API's ?

Comment: I am not sure about how to access the fields. I have to use groovy. REST API's should be fine but i am not sure about JIRA's API and usages

Comment: It would be better if you can share the fields that you want to access ,i have accessed Jira fileds using REST API's

Comment: @phaneesh I have to update fix branch and fix versions. Updated question with the screenshot. Please suggest

Comment: @phaneesh any idea how to do this?